# calculating multiple percentages in a single MySQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I am new to complex SQL statements and need help.
I have managed to display half of the result set and struggling with remaining.

Result required:

```
PSU |  pregnancy number| pregnancy percentage | % of live birth out of the pregnancy number.
1   |          2       |          67%         |         40%
2   |          1       |          33%         |         80%
```

With the sql written below , I have managed to get the first 3 columns.

The 2nd and the 3rd columns required where statement of `fieldname = 'Q111'`. While the 4th column requires percentage with where statement of `fieldname = 'Q112`. 
How do I combine different where statements together.

```sql
SELECT sms_psu.name1 AS PSU,
       woman_data.answertext  AS NumberOfPreg,
       Count(woman_data.answertext) / (SELECT Count(woman_data.answertext)
                                       FROM   woman_data
                                              INNER JOIN sms_household
                                                      ON woman_data.prim_key =
                                                         ms_household.hhid
                                              INNER JOIN sms_psu
                                                      ON sms_psu.psu =
                                                         sms_household.psu
                                       WHERE  sms_psu.state = 19
                                              AND sms_psu.district = 1
                                              AND sms_psu.psu = 2
                                              AND fieldname = 'Q139') AS
       totalcpuntpreg
FROM   woman_data
       INNER JOIN sms_household
               ON woman_data.prim_key = sms_household.hhid
       INNER JOIN sms_psu
               ON sms_psu.psu = sms_household.psu
WHERE  sms_psu.state = 19
       AND sms_psu.district = 1
       AND sms_psu.psu = 2
       AND fieldname = 'Q111'
GROUP  BY woman_data.answertext,
          sms_household.psu
```

---

Gordon,Your suggestion helped me a lot.I updated my query accordingly.The issue that i am having write now is that iam getting an additional row for Q112

PSU |  pregnancy number| pregnancy percentage | % of live birth out of the pregnancy number.
1   |     2       |    67%    |  40% 
2   |     1       |    33%    |   80%
2   |     1       |    0%     |   20% (3rd row is additional for Q112)

But I do not require the Q112 entry while i do group by. Can i use group by in case statements and in main where statement separately ? I tried using "having " with group by but dint get expected result.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  It's very helpful if you figure out how to display your code logically; I have edited your question in an attempt to do that. It's also helpful to have more information about your data.

Comment: Where does the `fieldname` column come from? There's no table alias in front of it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT sms_psu.name1 AS PSU,
       woman_data.answertext  AS NumberOfPreg,
       SUM(fieldname = 'Q111') / SUM(fieldname = 'Q139') AS pregnancyPercentage,
       SUM(fieldname = 'Q112') / SUM(fieldname = 'Q139') AS liveBirthPercentage
FROM   woman_data
       INNER JOIN sms_household
               ON woman_data.prim_key = sms_household.hhid
       INNER JOIN sms_psu
               ON sms_psu.psu = sms_household.psu
WHERE  sms_psu.state = 19
       AND sms_psu.district = 1
       AND sms_psu.psu = 2
GROUP  BY woman_data.answertext,
          sms_household.psu  
HAVING SUM(fieldname = 'Q111') > 0
```

The query first retrieves rows with all `fieldname` values and groups them same as before. When counting, only specific `fieldname` entries are counted (using the `SUM(condition)` trick) as necessary. To make sure that the output contains only groups that have rows with `fieldname = 'Q111'`, the `SUM(fieldname = 'Q111') > 0` condition was added (as a HAVING clause).

Answer (score 0):

Your query is, as you mentioned, complex. It's hard for somebody unfamiliar with your schema to make sense of it.  So I will offer a general suggestion for queries that summarize multiple items.

Use a decent client program that lets you save query text.  If it also prettyprints (formats) your query text that is helpful.

Develop and test each summary query separately. Make sure each one, standing alone, produces the correct summary result you need from it.

Then, join those queries together on the reporting key (PSU in your case I believe) so it produces the multiple summary results.  Make sure it is working.

Put a query name and version number in a comment right after the SELECT statement: for example,

```
SELECT /* pregnancy outcomes 1.1 */
       sms_psu.name1 AS PSU,
       woman_data.answertext AS NumberOfPreg, etc.
```

This will let you use the MySQL `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` to figure out which exact queries are running.

Finally, if the result query (consisting of lots of nested subqueries) is too slow for your application's requirements, optimize it.

If you follow these steps, your next step is to develop your `% live birth` summary query, I believe.

Comment: Thank you Ollie Jones.I was posting for the first time in any forum so took many things for granted. Will be careful next time onwards.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is:  the CASE statement.

The idea is to extend the outer WHERE clause to include all rows you care about.  Then, use a CASE statement in the SELECT clause to filter the rows, on a single variable basis.

I tried to put this together as:

```
SELECT sms_psu.name1 AS PSU,
       woman_data.answertext AS NumberOfPreg,
       Count(case when sms_psu.state = 19 AND sms_psu.district = 1 AND sms_psu.psu = 2 AND fieldname = 'Q111'
                  then woman_data.answertext
             end) /
       (SELECT Count(woman_data.answertext)
        FROM woman_data INNER JOIN
              sms_household
              ON woman_data.prim_key = ms_household.hhid INNER JOIN
              sms_psu
              ON sms_psu.psu = sms_household.psu
        WHERE  sms_psu.state = 19 AND sms_psu.district = 1 AND sms_psu.psu = 2 AND
               fieldname = 'Q139'
       ) AS totalcpuntpreg,
       Count(case when sms_psu.state = 19 AND sms_psu.district = 1 AND sms_psu.psu = 2 AND fieldname = 'Q112'
                  then woman_data.answertext
             end) /
       (SELECT Count(woman_data.answertext)
        FROM woman_data INNER JOIN
              sms_household
              ON woman_data.prim_key = ms_household.hhid INNER JOIN
              sms_psu
              ON sms_psu.psu = sms_household.psu
        WHERE  sms_psu.state = 19 AND sms_psu.district = 1 AND sms_psu.psu = 2 AND
               fieldname = 'Q139'
       ) AS totalcpuntpreg

FROM woman_data INNER JOIN
     sms_household
     ON woman_data.prim_key = sms_household.hhid INNER JOIN
     sms_psu
     ON sms_psu.psu = sms_household.psu
WHERE sms_psu.state = 19 AND sms_psu.district = 1 AND sms_psu.psu = 2 AND
      fieldname in ('Q111', 'Q112')
GROUP BY woman_data.answertext
        sms_household.psu
```

However, I might have missed some details.

Comment: Thank you Ollie Jones and Gordon Linoff. I was posting for the first time in any forum so took many things for granted. Will be careful next time onwards.

Comment: Gordon, With your suggestion I updated my query but got another issue with it. I have explained it in the post as an answer.Basically with the above query  , I am getting an additional row for Q112. 
I need the records of Q112 only to calculate the percentage in my 4th column and not add any rows.

Comment: What this is saying is that there is data for Q112 where answertext and psu is not represented in Q111.  Do you really want to filter this data out?